# Usage of 'nonlocal' keyword in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

Below program asks for `nonlocal` keyword with `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'balance' referenced before assignment`

```
>>> def make_withdraw(balance):
    """Return a withdraw function with a starting balance."""
    def withdraw(amount):
        if amount > balance:
            return 'Insufficient funds'
        balance = balance - amount
        return balance
    return withdraw

>>> withdraw = make_withdraw(101)
>>> withdraw(25)
```

But, below program does not give such error when inner function `shift` refers to `lst` before assignment as `temp = lst[0]`.

```
def shift_left(lst, n):
    """Shifts the lst over by n indices

    >>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> shift_left(lst, 2)
    >>> lst
    [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
    """
    assert (n > 0), "n should be non-negative integer"
    def shift(ntimes):
        if ntimes == 0:
            return
        else:
            temp = lst[0]
            for index in range(len(lst) - 1):
                lst[index] = lst[index + 1]         
            lst[index + 1] = temp
            return shift(ntimes-1)
    return shift(n)
```

How do I understand/compare these two scenarios?

Comment: Where/how does the program "ask for `nonlocal` keyword", and what does that even mean?

Comment: @StefanPochmann if I say `nonlocal balance` before making this condition `if amount > balance:` it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never assigning to `lst`, only to `lst[index]`. The two concepts are not quite the same thing.

The line:

```
lst = some_other_value
```

would rebind the name `lst` to point to another object. The line:

```
lst[index] = some_other_value
```

alters the object referenced by the name `lst`, by binding a specific index in that sequence to something else. The name `lst` itself is never altered, so there is no ambiguity here as to what scope that name belongs in.

In Python scoping, only binding operations on the name itself count. Binding operations are not just (direct) assignments, but also include function parameters, function and class definitions, `import` statements and targets for `except .. as`, `with .. as` and the target in `for ... in` loops. If a name is bound to in a given scope, it is considered *local*, in all other cases Python looks for the name in a parent scope, with the outermost scope being `global`.

Assignments to *subscriptions* (using `[...]`) are not binding operations in this context.

See the [*Naming and binding* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) of the Python Execution Model documentation, as well as the *[Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)* post.

Comment: sorry I have edited my question, because accessign index in not the right example!!! am talking about referring a variable before assignment. In first case, it is `balance` and second case it is `lst`.

Comment: @overexchange: that is not very helpful, because your question is now simply a duplicate. `lst1` is not non-local because you assigned to it.

Comment: @overexchange: since my answer answers your new version and your old version, but your old version has some unique aspects, I rolled back your edit.

Comment: For your point: "The name `lst` itself is never altered", In the inner function, I could do `lst = [1, 2, 3]`, it works

Comment: @overexchange: yes, you can assign something to the name `lst` in the inner function. It is then a local *everywhere in that function*. Move that assignment to the end of the function and you'll get an `UnboundLocal` exception.

Comment: you mean to say, if expr `balance = balance - amount` wouldn't exist, I would not get this `unboundlocal` error.

Comment: @overexchange: exactly, because that is a binding operation.

Comment: Now I understood the meaning of your statement: "Assignments to subscriptions (using `[...]`) are not binding operations"